# How to dive into IoT world with just high-level programming experience

Tags: sensor, bluetooth-low-energy, tutorial

I came from a high-level programming world and recently got a bit bored. Now I want to dive into IoT subject and start a hardware side project. I was thinking if there is a *Hello World* IoT tutorial, that would teach me how to:

1. Use modern BLE module, ARM processor, and a nice sensor (for example the ambient temperature sensor or ECG - whatever works).
2. Choose proper electronic parts and read the data sheet.
3. Use KiCad or Eagle to draw schematics.
4. Write firmware for my device.
5. Connect everything all together.

Basics of electronics in the tutorial would be a plus (but there already exist a massive amount of nice tutorials about electronics).

Comment: You might be better off starting with an evaluation board that supports the kind of connectivity you want. That will ensure you have some working hardware to start with.

Comment: There seem to be quite a few ARM processor based boards to choose from. Recently I had a reason to get one of the nxp kinetis boards. But there are many other choices, also. There is a lot of example code for kinetis that you can download and look at. I am not endorsing it. Other choices may be better. I had a specific external reason to pick kinetis.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know high-level programming languages I would suggest you to start with [NodeMCU](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html). It has WiFi, is programmed in lua, can do real-world sensor interfacing while still being [easy to start with](http://lb9mg.no/2015/05/30/first-steps-with-nodemcu/).